# copy paste from differetn worksheets having same target

Tags: vba, for-loop, copy, iteration, paste

I have to do the same copy paste but for more columns that are in different worksheets (4,6,8,etc) not in sequence just as j...

The rows are working with the arrRows (thanks Tinman)

- But for the columns, I tried 3 fors (one work the sheets, one for the columns, one for the rows) is not working because it doesnt jump to the next j (after going through all the n's just goes to the next column) not the next sheet (this is what I need)
- I tried another path (current code) I am unable to find a sequence that having j as a variable can tackle the correct number in the arrcolumns..perhaps I can do a do..loop?

```
Sub GHM()

    
    
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim n As Long, r, c As Long
    Dim arrRows, arrColumns As Variant
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    
   
    
    For j = 4 To 18 Step 2
    
    
    
    
    Set Source = Workbooks("180610_book1.xlsm").Worksheets(j).Cells
    Set Target = Workbooks("180610_book2.xlsm").Worksheets("RAW DATA").Cells

    
   


    arrRows = Array(5, 10, 15, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 61, 66, 71, 79, 84, 89, 94, 102, 107, 112, 117, 122, 127, 135, 140, 148, 153, 158, 166, 171, 179, 184, 189, 194)
    arrColumns = Array(9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44)
    
    
    c = arrColumns(j - 4)
    
    For n = 2 To 35
         r = arrRows(n - 2)
        Target.Cells(r, c).Resize(1, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Source.Cells(4, n).Resize(5, 1).Value)
    Next
   Next
  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a do until with a counter only for columns and it worked

```
    Dim j, x As Integer
    Dim n As Long, r, c As Long
    Dim arrRows, arrColumns As Variant
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range

    x = 0
    For j = 4 To 18 Step 2

        Set Source = Workbooks("180610_SequencingScenarioTEST1.xlsm").Worksheets(j).Cells
        Set Target = Workbooks("180610_SequencingScenarioTEST1.xlsm").Worksheets("RAW DATA").Cells
        arrRows = Array(5, 10, 15, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 61, 66, 71, 79, 84, 89, 94, 102, 107, 112, 117, 122, 127, 135, 140, 148, 153, 158, 166, 171, 179, 184, 189, 194)
        arrColumns = Array(9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44)

        Do
            c = arrColumns(x)
            For n = 2 To 35

                r = arrRows(n - 2)
                Target.Cells(r, c).Resize(1, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Source.Cells(4, n).Resize(5, 1).Value)
            Next                                      'for each column being transpose to row in target sheet

            x = x + 1

        Loop Until x <> x + 1                         'for each columns in raw data = the different scenarios
    Next                                              'for j=new sheet
End Sub
```